# Am I penalized for trying to "improve" a test edit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I got a suggested edit that seemed really weird:

https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/232686

I couldn't quite figure out what the edit was trying to achieve, and toggling between "markdown" and "rendered output" didn't make it more clear so I looked at the [original question](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/232686) which was kind of thin but actually had a good answer, and wanted to see the suggested edit in place. I hit "improve" -- I already suspected I was going to cancel the improvement and reject the edit, but I wanted to at least see if looking at the whole thing made any sense of what the edit was trying to achieve.

Instead, I got a message asserting that I'd failed a test. Now the edit is marked `Review audit failed 6 mins ago:`

I'm frustrated because I feel like I have this "fail" stamp now and I actually just wanted to see the edit in the context of the full post.

Am I penalized for this in some way? It seems unfair, since I didn't accept the edit.

Comment: Please note, that failing an audit once in a while is not bad. Next time with similar edits, just reject them.

Comment: Still, the audits don't work the way they are supposed to do: they **should** catch us when we "don't pay attention" not when we work carefully - at least that's what the wording implies.

Comment: The system has taught me to accept a blatantly duplicated answer as perfectly acceptable when working through the first posts review queue. Brilliant.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, you *can't improve* an edit like that. Reasons:

1. It defaces the post. Replacing `Reading state information... Done` with something else is not necessary. It obscures a message in the post about apt-get.
2. The reason of the edit doesn't apply. An edit that says "improved link display" but doesn't improve any link must be summarily rejected, you don't need to edit over to fix it, just reject it. In fact the post doesn't have any link to speak of.
3. It doesn't improve the quality of the post, but makes it more unreadable. "locate" isn't an equivalent of "view plug in 13 10", and will never be. The same with the other replacements, it isn't the way you improve a post.

If you need to see the whole post, just press "Rendered output":

[image]

The markdown one is good too if you can't see any important change:

[image]

BTW, that is an audit and it's easily recognizable by the words "baba ji" which is a known spammer of AU.

Comment: I agree. The edit was pure crap. But "improve" is the only way to see the full edited post. The original question was so thin I thought maybe seeing it in context would explain what the edit was getting at. I just don't think I should be penalized for looking at the edit in the context of the full post, which is very different from approving the edit.

Comment: @Amanda check my edit

Comment: @Amanda Clicking improve should really only be done when you actually intend to improve the edit. If you want to see the entire question you can click on the title, or look at the markdown view.